# how to make ubuntu 14.10 recognize Dell u2312hm screen?

Tags: nvidia, display, 14.10

I just installed 14.10 on a new computer but it does not recognize the display (dell u2312hm) I tried installing the NVIDIA driver 331.89 but it did not help.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Through which port have you connected your display?

Comment: VGA________________

Answer (score 0):

Try using only VGA the first time you configure it, i had many problems with HDMI and ended up using first VGA to configure it.